# Merge three arrays in different iterations(incrementation) - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements, nested-loops

I have three arrays of numbers:

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const arr2 = [10, 20];
const arr3 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];
```

i want to join them in a way where every time 'n' numbers are added (n starts with 1..2..3..and so on)
at first - one of each array, then 2 of each array, 3 of each untill the array is empty

so the final result should look like this:

```
finalArray = [1, 10, 100, 2, 3, 20, 200, 300, 4, 5, 6, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000,];
```

i tried and tested a couple of nested loops methods but couldn't define the stop conditions, i just added all the numbers multiple times without success.

i tried using Concat(), but couldn't figure the right order

```
let finalArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arrF3.length; i++) {
  finalArray.push(arrF3[i]);
  for (let j = 0; j < arrF2.length; j++) {
    finalArray.push(arrF2[j]); 
    for (let k = 0; k < arrF1.length; k++) {
      
    }
  }
}
console.table(finalArray);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Loop until the end of the longest length list, then take i + 1 elements.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const arr2 = [10, 20];
const arr3 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];

const finalArray = [];

let totalI = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length, arr3.length); i++) {
  finalArray.push(
    ...arr1.slice(totalI, totalI + i + 1),
    ...arr2.slice(totalI, totalI + i + 1),
    ...arr3.slice(totalI, totalI + i + 1)
  );
  totalI += i + 1;
}

console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: Thanks now i see how to use the slice() method in JS.
but can u explain what 'totalI' stands for?
is it for the iteration or to know where i ended going over all three arrays?

Comment: @PheonixPadawan total i is a sum of all the `i` variables. `i` generally means `index` in for loops like this. It's `+ 1` since we're counting starting with 1 but the code needs to start at 0 because arrays are zero-based indexed in JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

This works for any number of arrays. Just keep slicing until all slices are empty.

```js
const arrays = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [10, 20],
    [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]
]


let res = [], pos = 0, len = 1;

while (1) {
    let slices = arrays.map(a => a.slice(pos, pos + len))
    if (slices.every(s => s.length === 0))
        break
    res = res.concat(...slices)
    pos += len
    len += 1
}

console.log(...res)
```